# Floor function, derivates, summation

Tags: real-analysis

Does this function have a derivative?
  $$f_p(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \frac{p}{4qx}+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor}x^2csc^{2}\left(j_kx\right) $$
How do I derive this function?

Comment: What do all of the variables mean?

Comment: j,p,q are arbitrary constants

Comment: Do you know the derivative of $x^2\csc(x)$? If so, it seems you should be able to take this derivative

Comment: I know calculate the derivative of $\displaystyle x^2csc^2(x)$, but the problem is the floor function, i don't know what a can make with this function.